# How to launch (start) emacs with a single window and choose the buffer of that window as default in the init.el file?

Tags: init-file, window, window-splitting

What statements in the init.el file can be added so that there is a single window shown as the default I have is split into 2 windows vertically aligned (equivalent to typing `C-x 1`)?

Then once there is only a single window showing, how to select the buffer for the window? Eg. open a shell in the buffer (`M-x shell`).

This question [other similar question](https://superuser.com/q/1034333/47618) produces 3 windows vertically aligned.

Comment: Start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file), and you will see that there is no split window. Consider how you are starting it otherwise (e.g. passing it arguments). Other than that, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If you need the effect of `C-x 1` at some point you can use `(delete-other-windows)` but you shouldn't be bothering to create extra windows that you need to delete. You are the master of your init file. Emacs just does what you tell it to do, starting with your init file.

Comment: @Drew, I put `(delete-other-windows)` into my init file, and it did not work, same split of the frame. Does it need to be placed in some particular order? How can I then prevent that initial redundant creation of windows I do not need?

Comment: Please read what I said, other than that. Something in your init file is creating multiple windows. We don't know what that is, or when they are created, or which of them is the selected window when you might want to use `delete-other-windows'. Unless you know all of that `delete-other-windows' won't be any help. You need to bisect your init file and find out which part of it is causing your problem.

Comment: @Drew, my init file does not have anything that specifies opening new windows. It is similar to the default window openings on fresh installation.

Comment: Do you see the same problem when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not, then *your init file is the problem*. It doesn't matter whether you see any code affecting windows in it. Something you are doing in it invokes some code that does something affecting windows. Bisect your init file, recursively, till you locate the problem. We cannot guess what you are doing in your init file. It's your file - unless you see the same problem without it then you are causing the problem yourself, with your init file.

Comment: @Drew, `emacs -Q` does fix the problem. I will look into the sequential process of removing commands to find the source, but am still wondering if there is a command at the end to simply reverse the previous splits

Comment: Bisecting is very quick - it's a binary search.

Comment: @Drew, I get this error `Symbol's value as variable is void: delete-other-windows`

Comment: Bisect your init file by commenting out 1/2 of it, then 3/4 of it, then 7/8, 15/16,...

Comment: @Drew, thank you! found the problem! Seems like an approach that can tackle most problems. I had a command that produced an error and the split screen was there to highlight that error. Now how do I get the shell to appear...? put a command that says open shell at the end of the init?

Comment: Glad you found your problem. Please post a separate question if you have  another question. And if you think this question is unlikely to help others you might consider deleting it.

Comment: @drew put option to close question. Cant find delete on the app

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP wants to delete it. He solved his problem and doesn't think the Q&A will help others.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the comment: Nothing except something in your init.el can cause the effect you are having now (if you didn't start Emacs with additional command line arguments). So there must be something in your init.el that creates a new window.

Here is something I put together to (hopefully) find what causes the window splitting.

First, add an advice to `split-window-right`. The lambda will be called before `split-window-right` was called. The lambda will print out the backtrace frame

```lisp
(advice-add 'split-window-right :before (lambda (&rest _) (print (backtrace-frames))))
```

Then to test it I defined a function that calls `split-window-right`.

```lisp
(defun some-function () (split-window-right))
```

Calling it prints this:

```lisp
((t backtrace-frames nil nil)
 (nil print
      ((backtrace-frames))
      nil)
 (t
  (lambda
    (&rest _)
    (print
     (backtrace-frames)))
  nil nil)
 (t apply
    ((lambda
       (&rest _)
       (print
        (backtrace-frames)))
     nil)
    nil)
 (t split-window-right nil nil)
 (t some-function nil nil)
 (t eval
    ((some-function)
     nil)
    nil)
 (t elisp--eval-last-sexp
    (t)
    nil)
 (t eval-last-sexp
    (t)
    nil)
 (t eval-print-last-sexp
    (nil)
    nil)
 (t funcall-interactively
    (eval-print-last-sexp nil)
    nil)
 (t call-interactively
    (eval-print-last-sexp nil nil)
    nil)
 (t command-execute
    (eval-print-last-sexp)
    nil))
```

You can find `some-function` is right before `split-window-right`.

This may solve your problem, may not. But I think it worth giving a try : )